# (Safe) Automatic refactor of nested JS files to flatter hierarchy

Tags: javascript, refactoring

probably a vain hope, but: 
I have inherited a react native app whose folder structure is excessively nested to my taste. I'd like a way to automatically move JS files *and their references* up the directory structure in certain cases. For example

```
src/containers/
  Accounts/
    index.js
    Login/
      Login.js
      index.js
    Signup/
      Signup.js
      index.js
 ...
```

would be refactored to

```
src/containers/
  Accounts/
    index.js
    Login.js
    Signup.js
 ...
```

Comment: What environment are you developing in? Are you looking for a shell script that moves the files?

Comment: sure, bash would be fine. I'm using WebStorm (intelliJ) but the automatic refactor did not update the references all all the way. It may be that this is impossible to do statically

Comment: It surely is possible, but if you want your file contents updated to automatically track the file references, then it will be *complicated* for sure. How many folder do you have that you need to move? Likely it's faster to do manually.